# How to assign random 4-digit number for Selenium port in Jenkinsfile

Tags: random, jenkins-pipeline

Using `Jenkinsfile` for Pipeline as code, I want to create a random 4-digit Port number as follows:
[current option using build_number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvrz8.png)

This example I tried prefix of 47 + build number, which doesn't work if build number is single digit or more than 3 digits. But randomInt() hasn't worked in `Jenkinsfile` before.